# zend framework 2 controller's action arguments

Tags: zend-framework2

I had this public function in ApplicationController

```
public function indexAction($bar) {
    echo $bar; 
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

How I can pass this argument? I've tried http://localhost/zf2/public/application/index/index?bar=foo 
but this not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab it from [params controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params).

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $bar = $this->params()->fromQuery('bar');
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: there aren't other ways? in zend framework 1 was easiest and fastest

Comment: Almost same length as `$bar = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('bar');`

Comment: if I have to check the value of _GET I superglobal necessarily have to do so many IF? I can define it as function arguments?

Comment: You can look into abstractActionController, in code you will see how are actions called. You can change it.

Comment: thanks! but how I can get all action's parameters list in my abstractActionController?